# How can I display all my model predicted values using whisker plots?

Tags: r, linear-regression, mixed-models

I'm working with a linear mixed model with sex and diel (day/night) as my predictors and depth displacement as my response in R. Here is the model:

```
displacement_lmm_hour <- lmer(Displacement~sex*Light + (1|Hour), data = avg_depth_df_hour)
```

I want to create a whisker plot displaying each predicted value for each of my predictors from the model. So, I tried using *dwplot* from the `dotwhisker()` library in R.

```
dwplot(displacement_lmm_hour, effects = "fixed")
```

This is what it came out with:

[image]

As you can see, it is only showing the first 'sets' (if you will) of predicted values. Ie. there's no males, or day time values shown. I realize this comes from the model itself and the summary() table of the model only shows those as well. But, how can I show these values for the 'hidden' predicted values that also come from the model?

I also tried using '''plot_model''', which allowed me to separate my predicted values, but I don't think the error bars are correct (why I tried the whisker plots instead)

```
plot_model(displacement_lmm_hour, type = "pred", terms = c("sex","Light"), axis.title = c("Sex", "Displacement")
```

[image]

Do you have an idea how to accomplish this using the dwplot function? Or another way to accomplish this in general?

Thanks!

Comment: You can make whisker plots with `ggplot()` from `ggplot2` package. `ggplot2` will give you more control over how you would want your plot to look, but you may have to learn a lot of new functions if you never used it before. `ggplot2` is likely the most commonly used plotting package in R, so it's good if you learn how to use it. Alternatively, I did a quick Google search and found [`sjp.lmer`](https://cran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2017-12-15/web/packages/sjPlot/vignettes/sjplmer.html) for plotting `lmer()` models. Would that be useful for you?

Comment: Hi there, I think I'm okay with what function to use, more so about extracting the correct values from my model to plot. And plotting them all, rather than just the predictors that show up on the summary table